# USB-C hub partially working

Tags: 20.04, usb

I have an USB-C hub offering HDMI, VGA, Ethernet and a few USB3 ports ([this NOVOO docking station](https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B08H85QF1G)), but I can only make one of them work. What happens:

- HDMI works fine, I can plug my monitor and use it through the hub.
- Ethernet blinks like there is some network, but the system doesn't seem to detect the new network connection.
- USB3 aren't detected by the OS. If I plug my phone, it does start charging, though.

I have tested the following commands when pluging the hub with a USB device connected to it (USB key):

- `/var/log/syslog`: nothing appears when plugging things
- `dmesg`: no difference before and after plugging it
- `lsusb -v`: no difference before and after plugging it

The simple fact that the HDMI works is a sign that my USB-C port isn't only for charging. But most people on the web seem to have the opposite problem (USB-C hub with working USB ports but non-working HDMI)...

How can I debug this?

An extract of my lsusb only show other devices directly plugged to my computer:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0408:5343 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP HD Camera (MY WEBCAM)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:0aaa Logitech, Inc. PRO X (MY HEADSET)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. (BLUETOOTH)
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1bcf:0053 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. USB Optical Mouse  (MY MOUSE)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**Edit:** I ended up sending back the hub as I couldn't find any solution...

Comment: What USB hub is it? Can you [edit] your question with a link to it?

Comment: Thanks. I just did.